# Stream Out Part of a string

Tags: c++, string, stream, iomanip

I want to stream out a `std::string` but I want to be able to do it without the first two characters or the last two characters.

For example:

```
string foo{"bu blah blah blee le"};

cout << foo.substr(2) << endl << foo.substr(0, foo.size() - 2) << endl;
```

Are there any `iomanip` tools for that? or should I just go ahead and construct the temporary `string`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `cout.write`:

```
cout.write(foo.c_str() + 2, foo.size() - 4);
```

which also returns the stream, so you can do:

```
cout << "First two: ";
cout.write(foo.c_str(), 2) << "\nAll but first two: ";
cout.write(foo.c_str() + 2, foo.size() - 2) << '\n';
```

Comment: It's not streamable like that.